# classes could not be instantiated org.osmdroid.views.MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I am a osmdroid mapview but in layout it shows error. Please tell what to do.

http://www.pics9.com/images/30811182985062401036.jpg

http://www.pics9.com/images/51249770188868693824.jpg

Comment: It's impossible to say unless you post your code

Comment: Yes it is necessary to have code, @NickT i have just given the answer based on my assumption.

Comment: what codes should i paste its too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphical layout never works properly when trying to display a MapView. I've used both a Google Maps view and an OSM (Osmdroid) map view in my project. The project works OK but you will have to run it to see how the view comes out. The graphical layout of my views show exactly the same '.. could not be instantiated' error as you have. You will need an API key for you Google map as PM said.

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout image, it seems that you havent put the API key. So put the API key and check it again.

To Generate Maps APY key to be used in MapView Android, follow this steps:

1. Type keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore at the command prompt
2. Then enter MD5 fingerprint in a textbox showing here: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: That is necessary for the Google map view but not for the OpenStreet Map view.

Comment: i have just removed api key in the SS. But in real i have api